# Differentiate between 10-based Locator and Other Locators

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geocoding

In ESRI documentation, it states that the `IAdvancedIntersectionGeocoding` interface is only available for use in older locators (9.3.1 and below). I have verified this statement. One major problem is that 10-based locators still implements `IAdvancedIntersectionGeocoding` even though you cannot use it.

I want to be able to differentiate between locator versions to either be able to implement `IAdvancedIntersectionGeocoding` or not. Documentation states that `ESRIFDOAddressLocator` represents a pre-10 locator, while `ESRIGen2AddressLocator` represents a 10 locator.

I have been comparing the locator returned from the currently active locator to these two objects to determine versions, but they both return true (even if I select the 9.3.1 locators).

Is there any way to differentiate between locator versions? If not, is there any other interface or object I missed to be able to return standardized intersections?

Diagram:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Checking against `ESRIGen2AddressLocator` and `ESRIFDOAddressEditor` seems to be a problem only after Service Packs are installed. I have not drilled down to which one, but if ArcMap does not have a service pack, these checks work fine. I have logged a bug with ESRI to see if we can get this resolved.